# Exclude folder in my Site for Enterprise Single Sign-On

Tags: single-sign-on

I have a site under Microsoft Enterprise Single Sign-On. In a folder located in the site I have a Web Service (WSDL) that I want to exclude from ESSO validation for consume from other application without ESSO.

**Can I do it?**

My site 
https://example.com

To Exclude:
https://example.com/**services**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I found the solution.

You can especify in web.config the folder to exclude:

```
<location path="ExcludedFolder">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```